# Importing .csv file to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am aware of the procedure to import a .csv file to phpmyadmin. But the values in my columns contains paragraphs or long sentences which may contain 'commas'. Therefore I was to use another delimiter to seperate my columns instead of a 'comma'. For example a 'semicolon'. But whenever I use a 'semicolon' as a delimiter, phpmyadmin doesn't accept it. If anyone has been successful at using a different delimiter, please share the steps u followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin, click the table, and then click the Import tab at the top of the page.

Browse and open the csv file. Leave the charset as-is. 
Uncheck partial import unless you have a HUGE dataset (or slow server). The format should already have selected “CSV” after selecting your file,

if not then select it (not using LOAD DATA). 
If you want to clear the whole table before importing, check “Replace table data with file”.

Optionally check “Ignore duplicate rows” if you think you have duplicates in the CSV file.

Now the important part, set the next four fields to these values:

```
Fields terminated by: ,
Fields enclosed by: “
Fields escaped by: \
Lines terminated by: auto
```

Currently these match the defaults except for “Fields terminated by”, which defaults to a semicolon.

Now click the Go button, and it should run successfully.

**Happy SQling :)**

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply. Helped a lot! :)

Comment: I also find this helpfullll